# IIS worker process overlapping

Tags: iis-8, w3wp, worker-process, worker-processes

I have an application hosted in IIS 8 and it's application pool is set to auto recycle after 10000 requests. But at times when an application pool is recycled. The new app pool keeps on overlapping.. and the old one doesn't get abandoned.

Expected result: App pool should not overlap after auto recycling.

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Learn what is `disallowOverlappingRotation`,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/#attributes

Though you really should consider setting it to `true` and modify your web app to adapt to that overlapping behavior.

Comment: Hello LEx Li, Thank you for your help, when I set the value to true, once the requests are full and another instance is started, somewhere between disabling the overlapping is crashing my web application. Any Suggestions to fix this?